# JSON object clone

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

```
this.a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
this.b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

After doing this,i found that a and b have some sort of link that i change value of a, sometimes b also changes.
I want to know how to make a and b don't effect each other's value

Comment: no, they don't have any connection at all - please show code that does and I'll be surprised

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because assertions that are contrary to specified behaviour should include code to support the assertion.

Comment: you must have written some code somewhere which alters these values, and you haven't realised. There's no built-in mechanism which would do this. Unfortunately we haven't seen the rest of your code so we can't help you. It sounds like you need to narrow down the problem to where it's occurring, so I suggest you step through your code with the debugger and watch the values of your variables to determine which code is changing them.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is somewhere else, `this.a` and `this.b` can not have the same value. To prove my point look at the example below:

```js
var data = { x: 5, y: 6 };
var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
a.x = 1;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

`a` and `b` have different values and are not connected. Changing `a` does not affect `b`